# Use random id in Apache config

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to track unique requests in my application (PHP) and access (Apache) logs.

My proposed solution:

1. Apache generates a unique id and sets it as a header or environment variable.
2. PHP uses the the header/environment variable in its logging.
3. `mod_log_config` uses the value in its logging.

This way, I can track the activity of a single request in logs.

But I'm not sure how I can do the first part (or even if I can).

Can I configure Apache to generate a sufficiently unique (random) identifier for each request?

Comment: google analytics does this all for you. otherwise you need sessions\cookies (http is stateless)

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_unique_id.html

Comment: @Dagon, I am not trying to monitor unique sessions, but unique *requests*, i.e. everything in my server that happens from the HTTP request to the HTTP response.

Comment: every line in the access log is a unique request isent it?

Comment: Yes, but not my application (PHP) logs. For example, perhaps I log every time I make an external request, and I want to correlate them to my incoming requests.